# Should I select components based on peak current, RMS current, or average current?

Tags: components, switch-mode-power-supply, ratings

I am designing a SEPIC supply around an LT3757. The MOSFET will have ~6.5A pulses with a strange ramping pattern (see image), but the RMS current is only 3.38A and the average current is 2.60A. Assuming 50% over-rating, which rating should I be looking for in a suitable FET? Also, does this apply for resistors, inductors and capacitors, or are there other specifications to look out for?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you need to choose the part to survive the peak current.

Longer Answer:

I'd work your way through the SEPIC topology's design calculations again, your current ripple is really high, the difference between average and peak current should be much smaller.

The datasheet says that ΔIsw should be 20-40% of Isw(average max).  Or to use the datasheet's terminology χ should be between 0.2 and 0.4.

In your case (estimating by looking at the simulation output graph):

Isw(average max) = ~2.75A

ΔIsw = ~5.5A

χ = ~2.0

Try rerunning your simulation with larger L1/L2 inductors, this should reduce the ripple currents.

EDIT: try a larger cap for C3 also (try 10uf or a second 4.7uf in parrellel), the ESR / ESL of this part is also critical, check what the values of these are for your simulation model.

Comment: This is at maximum load (1.1 amps) so I expect the current ripple to be high.

Comment: I increased the inductor to 5.6µH, peak current is lower, but RMS is the same.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't change anything, you should be looking at max load and the datasheet's calculation are at max load, X should be 0.2-0.4 not 2.0.

Comment: exactly, increasing the value of the inductors reduces the swing of Isw, it shouldn't change RMS or average current.  reducing the peak current reduces strain on components, noise, supply ripple, etc.

Comment: I'm working off the datasheet's example on page 31. It's rated for 2A, I'm only needing 1.1A, so I've reduced the inductor's rating (from DRQ127 to DRQ73) and I've chosen a smaller FET.

Comment: Well the point and getting back to your original question here, is that your only considering average or RMS current, and what i'm saying is that you need to also consider peak current and that you can reduce the peak current you need to deal with by using a higher inductance part for L1/L2.

Comment: @JustJeff: The dielectric of what? the DC capacitor or something else? The peak voltage across C3 and M1 is <50V.

Comment: @Thomas O -- ok, nevermind. i was just generalizing.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "all of the above".

For saturation of the chokes, you need to worry about the peaks. If the choke saturates before your transistor turns off, your peaks will be much higher than you expected! Which has effect on things like EMF spray and inductive kicks, but also on the RMS currents, and thus heating. Not to mention making your entire system non-linear and difficult to control.

Heating for most components, including FETs, is about RMS current. Power loss is proportional to the square of the RMS current. One exception is if you're talking about a junction drop (say across a diode, BJT, or IGBT). Thermally, those components can be roughly modeled as a fixed voltage source in series with a resistance. The power loss in the resistance is proportional to the square of the RMS current, like any other component. But the loss in the fixed voltage source is proportional to the average current. So average current *can* matter for heating.

Now, RMS current is a function of peak current. What function depends on the shape of the wave; you can get the same average current and wildly different RMS currents. A 1 mS 1000A pulse has the same average current as a continuous 1A DC, but over 30x higher RMS. So by reducing your peaks and otherwise maintaining the same general wave shape, you should also reduce the RMS current.

So if you know the RMS current through the FET, and the RDS of the FET, you can find the losses in the FET. Knowing your ambient temperature, the max junction temperature of the FET, and the thermal resistance between the junction and ambient (accounting for any heat sink attached), you should be able to determine whether a given FET will survive the currents.